# multi level __getitem__ override issues

Tags: python, object, dictionary

So I have a custom Python object that behaves like a dict, but does some self parsing and self validation.

I am editing `__setitem__` to validate attempts to update the dict. This works fine for top-level items in the `dict`, but in sub-dicts, I cannot seem to detect that the change is occurring, even though it IS occurring.

Example:

```
"command":{
"name":"go.py",
"arguments":[
    {
    "variable":"length",
    "value":100
    }

]

 }

# in my object
    def __setitem__(self,key,item):
        print key
        if key is 'name':
            assert type(item) is str or type(item) is unicode, 'Type of name is '+str(type(item))+' should be str'
            assert item.endswith('.py'), 'command name must end in .py'
            self.name = item
        else:
            self.__dict__[key]=item
```

To figure out how to handle the multi level stuff, I wanted to print out the key. When I test this, I find that the name editing works perfectly, and whenever I make a change, it dutifully prints 'name'. But if I change arguments, 
**nothing prints, but the change is made.** This is very frustrating. Any hints regarding how to validate this multi-level input?

Comment: Do **not** use `is` to compare for equality! The line `key is 'name'` **will** fail in some circumstances. Use `key == 'name'`. Also to check for the type you should do `isinstance(item, (str, unicode))` which returns `True` if `item` is an instance of `str` or `unicode`.

Answer (score 0):

An object cannot control changes to other objects that it contains.  If you do `myObj['arguments']['variable'] = 2`, that is handled by the nested object, not the outer one.  This is because `myObj['arguments']` is first evaluated.  It evaluates to some object, and `__setiem__` is then called on *that* object, not on `myObj`.

If you want the outer object to control it, you need to make the nested object be some special object that "knows" where it is nested, and asks its parent if the modification is okay.

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are changing the nest object not using the set item of the lower object.

There are a few ways around this:

1.
Rather than use:

```
myObj['arguments']['variable'] = 2
```

Use:

```
myObj['arguments'] = {'variable':length,'value':2}
```

2.
Make the nested dictionary a custom object

3
Add set item methods

```
def setVariable(self, x):
    ****Assertions HERE ****
    self['arguments']['variable'] = 2
```